Docusaurus v3 SPA redirects to index on refresh
I have a Docusaurus v3 SPA. I have a pretty simple structure of my docs like this:
docs: [
"overview",
{
    type: 'category',
    label: 'API Gateway Endpoints',
    collapsed: false,
        items: [
            "api-gateway-endpoints/api-1",
            "api-gateway-endpoints/api-2",
            "api-gateway-endpoints/api-3",
            "api-gateway-endpoints/api-4"
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'category',
        label: 'Events',
        collapsed: false,
        items: [
        "events/events-1",
        "events/events-2"
        ],
    },
]
};

Building and serving it locally I don't have any problems. After deployment I can navigate everywhere without a problem except when I try to refresh some of the pages like {URL}/{BaseURL}/api-gateway-endpoints/api-1, then it displays the "overview" page for a second (the index page) and then redirects me back to the page I was refreshing.
In docusaurus.config.js:
**  url:"https://oneSite.com",
baseUrl: /first/draft/,
trailingSlash: false,**.
P.S : This is also my nginx.conf:
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    gzip  on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        absolute_redirect off;
        access_log off;

        # handle trailing slashes in /docs/
        rewrite ^/first/draft/(.*)/$ /first/draft/$1 permanent;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}

Can you please help me.. what could cause this problem? Thank you!
